# Specialization theorem for cohomology groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

If $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a proper lisse morphism and $\mathcal{F}$ is a torsion sheaf on $X$ then one has:
$$
(R^{i}f_{*}\mathcal{F})_{\overline{y}}\cong H_{c}^{i}(X_{\overline{y}},\mathcal{F}_{|X_{\overline{y}}})
$$
For any geometric point $\overline{y}$ of $Y$. I am wondering if this result can be extended to other kind of sheaf, e.g. if $\mathcal{F}=\mathbb{Q}_{l}$ or $\mathcal{F}$ is constructible. Thank you in advance